# Problems connecting a combobox signal to a std::function in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, combobox

I am creating a QWizard. For some of the QWizardPages, I give them a callback method in their constructors such the QWizardPage can set some properties on the QWizard.

Like so:

```
BWizard::BWizard(QWidget *parent, t::WindowFlags ): QWizard(parent, f), modelCheckedOut(false), selectedB(0){
  // Setup UI and add pages to wizard.
  ui.setupUi(this);
  // Make callbacks to set data onto Wizard instead of pages.
  auto makeLastPage = [this]()
  {
    int pageId = this->pageIds().last();
    this->removePage(pageId);
    this->modelCheckedOut = true;
  };
  auto setB = [this](int b)
  {
    this->selectedB = b;
  };
  addPage(new BWizardPage1(setB, this));
  addPage(new BWizardPage2(makeLastPage, this));
  addPage(new BWizardPage3(this));
}
```

On `BWizardPage1` I use `setB` function when Enter is pressed on a QLineEdit. I bind this in the constructor for `BWizardPage1`. This works fine:

```
QObject::connect(ui.searchField, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, this, [&]() {
  setB(5);
}
```

On `BWizardPage2` I use `makeLastPage` function when a combobox is changed. I bind this in the constructor for `BWizardPage2`. Once the combobox is changed, `makeLastPage` appears to be empty (or null).

```
 QObject::connect(ui.comboBox, static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(int)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), this, [&](int index) {
    makeLastPage();
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I pass the function as `std::function<void(void)> makeLastPage` and `std::function<void(int)> setB`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QObject::connect(ui.comboBox, static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(int)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), this, [&](int index) {
    makeLastPage();
}
```

By capturing `makeLastPage` by reference, you are capturing a reference to a function parameter. This will go out of scope after the function returns, leaving a dangling reference. Simply capture `makeLastPage` by value instead:

```
QObject::connect(ui.comboBox, static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(int)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), this, [=](int index) {
    makeLastPage();
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. But why does this not happen for `setB` in `BWizardPage1`?

Comment: Probably because it is undefined behavior. One thing which may occur when causing undefined behavior is that it may actually work as you had intended. It is difficult to tell without more code.